# How to create an instance array in PHP Attributes

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, annotations, doctrine

With Doctrine annotations it is possible to build the following mapping:

```php
/** 
 * @ORM\Table(indexes={
 *     @ORM\Index(name="first_index", columns={"username","password","email"}),
 *     @ORM\Index(name="second_index", columns={"email"}),
 *     @ORM\Index(name="third_index", columns={"email", "username","language"})
 * })
 */
class SomeClass
{
```

When refactoring this to PHP attributes I'm trying

```php
#[ORM\Table(
    indexes: [
        ['name' => 'first_index', 'columns' => ['username', 'password', 'email']],
        ['name' => 'second_index', 'columns' => ['email']],
        ['name' => 'third_index', 'columns' => ['email', 'username','language']]
    ]
)]
class SomeClass
{
```

but then my IDE complains this is a `string[]`, not the expected `ORM\Index[]` it needs.

(And also, Doctrine throws a MappingException with the message `Class "SomeClass" is not a valid entity or mapped super class.`.)

###### So practically speaking my question is: How can I get an array of `ORM\Index` instances inside of an `ORM\Table` attribute?

---

Other options I've tried:

```php
#[ORM\Table(
    indexes: [
        #[ORM\Index(name: 'first_index', columns: ['username', 'password', 'email'])],
    ]
)]
class SomeClass
{
```

but this breaks the attribute annotation.
Unfortunately the very basic [Doctrine attributes documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.9/reference/attributes-reference.html#attrref_table) does not demonstrate a relevant example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#[Index]` should be a separate statement instead of part of `#[Table]`:

```
#[ORM\Table]
#[ORM\Index(name: 'first_index', columns: ['username', 'password', 'email'])]
#[ORM\Index(name: 'second_index', columns: ['email'])]
#[ORM\Index(name: 'third_index', columns: ['email', 'username','language'])]
class SomeClass
{
```

See [this part](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.9/reference/attributes-reference.html#attrref_index) of the docs for an example.